# What is a Collection of Aggregates Referred to in Domain Driven Design?

Tags: terminology, domain-driven-design, aggregate

E.g. in a domain model with two aggregate roots:

- book
- author

Is there a specific term that refers to a collection of aggregates of the same root type (e.g. a collection of `books`)?

In [Confusion about the meaning of the word aggregate in domain driven design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/305319/163879) I read the term *aggregate type*, which might or might not fit, but I haven't found a direct mention in Evan's *blue book*.

Comment: AFAICT, it's simply *a collection of aggregates.*  Martin Fowler states *an invoice* as an example of an aggregate, so a bunch of them would simply be *a collection of invoices.*

Comment: Is BoundedContext what you're looking for? http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for your reply. Would you agree with VoiceOfUnreason that this is because the term aggregate is solely used to describe the concept of a transactional unit and thus there is no need to have a specific term for a collection of those (compared e.g. to table/row in a database context)?

Comment: @Jason Bounded Contexts are not really what I was after. With the distance of one day I realized that my question wasn't all that precise because I was really looking for something different. :) But that's a bit too far away from my original question so I leave that as it is and may be opening a follow up sometime. Nevertheless I find the question as is also interesting, namely if there was a specific term for a collection of aggregates of the same root type (seems there is none according to the answers).

Comment: Table/Row is also a collection.  It just happens to be a collection in a database, and table/row are convenient terms for something that has that particular shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a specific term that refers to a collection of aggregates (e.g. books or authors)?

No.

Keep in mind that the definition of aggregate is

> A cluster of associated objects that are treated as a unit for the purpose of data changes. External references are restricted to one member of the aggregate, designated as the root. A set of consistency rules applies within the aggregate's boundaries.

A union of two different transactional units is... not very interesting.